# Is it possible to target database entries based on a selected dropDown item in C# / ASPNET Webforms?

Tags: asp.net, database, list, drop-down-menu, webforms

Firstly, I would like to apologise for my poor title.

I am  building a CRUD application using ASPNET Webforms. One of my pages contains a dropDown which is populated with strings built from pulling entries from a SQL database (Id, FirstName, Surname).

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqqes.png)

I want to tie the entries in my dropDown to the Ids of items in my database, so that I may use then for update and delete functions.

I currently have code to populate a list with those IDs, but afterwards I realised that I have no idea how to link those entries to the IDs, or if it is even possible.

Current code to populate dropDown:

```cs
// string for populating crud_dropDown
            string commandString = "SELECT Id, FirstName, Surname FROM Users ORDER BY Id ASC;";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlCon);
            SqlDataReader myDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            // List to be populated with integers that correlate with with IDs in the database
            List<int> DbIds = new List<int>();

            while (myDataReader.Read())
            {
                // database IDs are are captured from database, saved as a string and converted to an integer
                string listId = myDataReader["Id"].ToString();
                int convtd_listId = Convert.ToInt32(listId);

                // captured IDs are added to DbIds List
                DbIds.Add(convtd_listId);

                // crud_dropDown is populated with strings built with DbIds contents and names read from the database
                string id = convtd_listId.ToString();
                string fn = myDataReader["FirstName"].ToString();
                string sn = myDataReader["Surname"].ToString();
                crud_dropDown.Items.Add(id + " - " + fn + " - " + sn);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming as you imply you're pulling the names & ID's from the database - you're creating a list of objects such that contains the information so you could do this:

Create a class to hold the details such as usersname and id properties, and a list of it's own type (example later).

Then in the code-behind for the page initialize the object and execute some sql to bind the db data to the objects and read it into the list:

```
User cUser = new User();

//From the sql:
while (reader.Read())
{
    User u = new User
    {
        UserID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]),
        UsersName = reader["Name"].ToString()
    };
    cUser.lstUsers.Add(u);
}

//Now we have the data just pipe it into the dropdownlist:
foreach (User u in cUser.lstUsers)
{
    //The dropdown control:
    ddlUsers.Items.Add(new ListItem(u.UsersName, u.UserID.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I already have a user class with these various properties, though it doesn't have IDs since the database auto-implements those its self. Am I correct in saying you propose I add a List to this class, and populate it with user objects based on rows from the database? And if so, will removing an object from this list then remove it from the database?

Comment: I think I now realise that my issue lies in the fact that I am not including the ID in my User class, and so there is nothing to compare to.

Comment: Yeah that's the big problem I'm afraid, if you just do a custom SQL query and pull it out manually should be fine hence the '//from the sql:' comment I put in

Comment: This does not seem to work. The list in the User class is not being populated. I could not seem to populate the dropDown with any of the properties of objects in the list, so I created a label which displays the count of the list, and it displays 0.

Comment: You make a user class.  Then a method that populates the list from the db. You then loop through each loop index accessing the id and name for the list item value and text. It's not populated because you didn't populate it

Comment: Scratch that. To use your example, I trying to add items to `User u` rather than `User cUser`. Everything seems to work now.

Comment: Having completed this process, it is definitely a cleaner and more object-oriented approach to populating my dropDown, but I am not sure how it helps me target database entries for use with methods, such as a generic deleteUser function.

Comment: Create a function that (using the userid value) takes the selected userid from the dropdownlist's value attribute its something like "ddlname.selecteditem. value" then executes a `delete from table where id = userid`

Comment: I had been hoping to avoid that since it meant I could only include the ID in my dropdown and not other concatenated information, though that is another issue. I am going to mark this as solved.